# How do I stop using repeated code in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to build a time card calculator for my sister to use at her job.

It has 16 different "time in" slots and 16 different "time out" slots. The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to calculate it, I'm having to run my code for each time in and time out, causing a bunch of repeated code. I feel like there's an easier way to do this with `while` loops, I just can't figure it out. Does anyone have any tips or ideas to help me figure this out?

In the code I only pasted the first section, in my program it actually has what I posted, just 15 more times.

**Edit:** I added the whole function

Also, I'm taking the totals, and the grand total, and putting them into `tkinter` labels using `textvariables`, which you can see at the bottom.

```
def calculate():

    fields = time_in1.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin1 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out1.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout1 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal1 = totalout1 - totalin1
    grandtotal1 = round(grandtotal1, 3)

    fields = time_in2.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin2 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out2.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout2 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal2 = totalout2 - totalin2
    grandtotal2 = round(grandtotal2, 3)

    fields = time_in3.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin3 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out3.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout3 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal3 = totalout3 - totalin3
    grandtotal3 = round(grandtotal3, 3)

    fields = time_in4.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin4 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out4.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout4 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal4 = totalout4 - totalin4
    grandtotal4 = round(grandtotal4, 3)

    fields = time_in5.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin5 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out5.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout5 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal5 = totalout5 - totalin5
    grandtotal5 = round(grandtotal5, 3)

    fields = time_in6.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin6 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out6.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout6 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal6 = totalout6 - totalin6
    grandtotal6 = round(grandtotal6, 3)

    fields = time_in7.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin7 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out7.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout7 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal7 = totalout7 - totalin7
    grandtotal7 = round(grandtotal7, 3)

    fields = time_in8.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin8 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out8.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout8 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal8 = totalout8 - totalin8
    grandtotal8 = round(grandtotal8, 3)

    fields = time_in9.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin9 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out9.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout9 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal9 = totalout9 - totalin9
    grandtotal9 = round(grandtotal9, 3)

    fields = time_in10.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin10 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out10.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout10 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal10 = totalout10 - totalin10
    grandtotal10 = round(grandtotal10, 3)

    fields = time_in11.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin11 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out11.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout11 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal11 = totalout11 - totalin11
    grandtotal11 = round(grandtotal11, 3)

    fields = time_in12.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin12 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out12.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout12 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal12 = totalout12 - totalin12
    grandtotal12 = round(grandtotal12, 3)

    fields = time_in13.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin13 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out13.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout13 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal13 = totalout13 - totalin13
    grandtotal13 = round(grandtotal13, 3)

    fields = time_in14.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin14 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out14.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout14 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal14 = totalout14 - totalin14
    grandtotal14 = round(grandtotal14, 3)

    fields = time_in15.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin15 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out15.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout15 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal15 = totalout15 - totalin15
    grandtotal15 = round(grandtotal15, 3)

    fields = time_in16.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalin16 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    fields = time_out16.get().split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    totalout16 = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)

    grandtotal16 = totalout16 - totalin16
    grandtotal16 = round(grandtotal16, 3)

    time_1_var.set(grandtotal1)
    time_2_var.set(grandtotal2)
    time_3_var.set(grandtotal3)
    time_4_var.set(grandtotal4)
    time_5_var.set(grandtotal5)
    time_6_var.set(grandtotal6)
    time_7_var.set(grandtotal7)
    time_8_var.set(grandtotal8)
    time_9_var.set(grandtotal9)
    time_10_var.set(grandtotal10)
    time_11_var.set(grandtotal11)
    time_12_var.set(grandtotal12)
    time_13_var.set(grandtotal13)
    time_14_var.set(grandtotal14)
    time_15_var.set(grandtotal15)
    time_16_var.set(grandtotal16)

    grandtotalall = (grandtotal1 + grandtotal2 + grandtotal3 + grandtotal4 + grandtotal5 + grandtotal6 + grandtotal7 +
                    grandtotal8 + grandtotal9 + grandtotal10 + grandtotal11 + grandtotal12 + grandtotal13 +
                    grandtotal14 + grandtotal15 + grandtotal16)

    grand_total_var.set(grandtotalall)
```

Comment: Extract the repeated code into its own function, passing in the data as needed. Also assign the return value to the specific variables.

Comment: You can change your code a little then  use loops!

Comment: This question belongs on the code review site.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and show at least one repeat so the pattern is more obvious.

Comment: @martineau I added the rest of the code for the function

Comment: _"I added the whole function"_ - please don't do that. We don't need a full program, we need a [mcve]. Is it really necessary to have 16 entries? Can't we still reproduce the problem with 15? 10? 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use loops. loops are used in situations like this when you want to repeat someting.
for example in your code you can have a list of grandtotals and do this:

```py
total_in = []
totoal_out = []
grand_totals = []
for i in range(0, 15):
    # calculate total_in
    total_in.append(calculated_total_in)
    total_out.append(calculated_total_out)
    grand_totals.append(round(total_in - total_out, 3))
```

This was all I could understand from what you are doing I hope you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Ussually in this cases you can use class to avoid repeat similar parts of your code, something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk 

class time:

    def __init__(self, frame, row, column):
        self.time_in = tk.Entry(frame)
        self.time_out = tk.Entry(frame)
        self.time_in.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: self.get_value_in))
        self.time_out.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: self.get_value_out))
        self.time_in.grid(row = row, column = column)
        self.time_out.grid(row = row, column = column + 1)
        self.totalout = 0
        self.totalin = 0
        self.grandtotal = 0

    def get_value_in(self):
        self.fields = self.time_in.get().split(":")
        self.hours = self.fields[0] if len(self.fields) > 0 else 0.0
        self.minutes = self.fields[1] if len(self.fields) > 1 else 0.0
        self.totalin = float(self.hours) + (float(self.minutes) / 60.0)
        self.update()

    def get_value_out(self):
        self.fields = self.time_out.get().split(":")
        self.hours = self.fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
        self.minutes = self.fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
        self.totalout = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.grandtotal = self.totalout - self.totalin
        self.grandtotal = round(self.grandtotal, 3)

    def get(self):
        return self.grandtotal


root = tk.Tk()
t = time(root, 0, 0)
print(time.get())
```

You can modify it, based on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

The source of the all code repetition is due to two things:

1. The use of separately-named variables for each quantity.
2. Not grouping those values and the operations upon them together in higher-level data structures like lists and classes.

Here's some example code that addresses both of these issues:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

NUMSLOTS = 16


class Slot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time_in = tk.StringVar(value='')
        self.time_out = tk.StringVar(value='')

    @staticmethod
    def _parse_time(str_var):
        fields = [(int(field) if field else 0) for field in str_var.get().split(":")]
        hours = int(fields[0]) if len(fields) > 0 else 0
        minutes = int(fields[1]) if len(fields) > 1 else 0
        return hours + (minutes/60)

    @property
    def elapsed_time(self):
        """ Compute number of hours between time_in and time_out attributes. """
        time_in = self._parse_time(self.time_in)
        time_out = self._parse_time(self.time_out)
        return time_out - time_in


def create_variables():
    global slots, time_vars

    slots = [Slot() for _ in range(NUMSLOTS)]
    time_vars = [tk.IntVar(value=0) for _ in range(NUMSLOTS)]


def calculate():
    for i, slot in enumerate(slots):
        time_vars[i] = slot.elapsed_time

    return sum(var for var in time_vars)


root = tk.Tk()
create_variables()

slots[0].time_in.set('08:30')
slots[0].time_out.set('10:00')
slots[1].time_in.set('10:15')
slots[1].time_out.set('12:00')

print(slots[0].elapsed_time)  # -> 1.5
print(slots[1].elapsed_time)  # -> 1.75
print(calculate())            # -> 3.25
```